R plotly- add_trace with transformed data
I notice that add_trace does not work on a plotly with transformed data. Is that right?
For example, using the code below I managed to produce a scatter plot of grouped data. How is it possible to use add_segments to make it look like a lollipop chart?
Also note that I want to apply the data transformation inside the plotly funs, in order to be able to use also crosstalk filters.
library(crosstalk)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)


set.seed(12345)
d <- data.frame(
  time = rep(0:9, 10),
  group = sample(paste0("Group_", seq(5)), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
  value = rnorm(n = 1000) + 1
)

sd1=SharedData$new(d )

fig <- plot_ly(
  data=sd1,
  type = 'scatter',
  color = ~group,
  y = ~value,
  x=~time,
  mode = 'markers',
  transforms = list(
    list(
      type = 'aggregate',
      groups =~ list(group,time),
      aggregations = list(
        list(
          target = 'y', func = 'mean', enabled = T
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


Adding a trace works fine for me. There's no added trace here to reproduce the issue you're having, either. What seems to be wrong? What happens when you run it? Does it not show up or is it not as expected? RIght now there's no way to answer this question...
